# Nginx configure: if not iPhone/iPad then 301 redirect to https

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, safari, ssl-certificate

I upgrade my website to https with startssl certification.
But Safari distrust the startssl certification.
So, I consider set the nginx, if it is http, and the UserAgent not contains iPhone/iPad, then 301 redirect to https.(It is mean, other browser will 301 to https.)
This is my tried:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  abc.com alias abc.com;
        ssl_certificate      D:\cert\1_abc.com_bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  D:\cert\abc.com.key;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;
        ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
        if ($scheme = http) && if ($http_user_agent !~* iPhone|iPad) {
            return   301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
        location / {
            root           D:/www;
            index  index.html index.htm default.html default.htm index.php;
            include        D:/www/up-*.conf;
        }
```

========OR==========

```
if ($scheme = http && $http_user_agent !~* iPhone|iPad)
```

========OR==========

But both of them, no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` directive can only contain simple conditionals. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) for details.

One approach would be to separate the `http` and `https` servers into separate `server` blocks.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  abc.com alias abc.com;

    if ($http_user_agent !~* "iPhone|iPad") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    include path/to/common/config;
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  abc.com alias abc.com;
    ssl_certificate      D:\cert\1_abc.com_bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  D:\cert\abc.com.key;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;
    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    include path/to/common/config;
}
```

It does involve duplicating common configuration across both `server` blocks, however, the `include` directive is available to offload any common configuration into a separate file (as illustrated above).

Answer (score 0):

A better solution for your problem will be a front-end redirect:

In the http webpage, include a js files located on the **https** version, that do only one thing: redirect to the same url but with https. So only client that trust your certificates will be redirected.

But whatever the solution, if the users gets an https link, it will be broken if they don't trust the certificate. And I hope you don't handle any personnal data, because you have an obligation of protection for these, even for people with iPads.

But of course, a better solution could be to use a trusted certificate, from let's encrypt for example.